# Laravel 5.1 migration error auto increment primary

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-5.1

I was learning Laravel for a some time, I create some basic project for myself, but today I was try to migrate table with more integers. But it still take an error.

Every integer try to be auto_increment and primary, it can be a problem, but I do not know, how to resolve it.

```
        Schema::create ('users', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments ('id');
        $table->string ('email')->unique();
        $table->string ('pass',250);
        $table->integer ('tickets',4);
        $table->integer ('tokens',4);
        $table->integer ('in_raffle',4);
        $table->text ('profile',500);
        $table->string ('ip',20);
        $table->integer ('ban',1);
        $table->integer ('notice',1);
        $table->timestamp ('last_login');

    });
```

https://s28.postimg.org/fh3uaqdct/screen2.jpg

Can somebody tell me, how can I resolve this problem? What to edit to work it properly?

Thanks a lot, have a nice day!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove seconds parameter in all `integer()`:

```
$table->integer('tickets');
$table->integer('tokens');
$table->integer('in_raffle');
$table->integer('ban');
$table->integer('notice');
```

The thing is secont parameter for `integer()` method is `autoIncrement` and it's treated as boolean. When you pass something different from `false`, Laravel thinks you want this integer to be `auto_increment`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Can you please tell me, how can I add size of integer? Because, all integers are now set to int(11) it is possible to add size in migration? If yes, how?

Thank you!

Comment: No it's not possible to do that in the migration unfortunately.  Keep in mind the size of the int doesn't have anything to do with the min or max value and is really only useful if you are using `zerofill`.  Here's a good write-up.  https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/entry/what_does_the_11_mean

Comment: You can't. What you can do is to use [these types of integer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#creating-columns): `tinyInteger`, `smallInteger`, `mediumInteger`, `integer`, `bigInteger`

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of the function looks like this:

```
public function integer($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)
```

So leave off the integer length, and it will work fine. If you want a smaller integer than a length of 11, you can use `smallInteger` or `mediumInteger`, which have lengths described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html).

Answer (score 0):

May

```
$table->tinyInteger('tickets');
$table->tinyInteger('tokens');
$table->tinyInteger('in_raffle');
$table->boolean('ban')->default(false);
$table->boolean('notice')->default(false);
```